# Using variables within a function (passing in a place holder)

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a function that I can pass a query into and loop through items items in chunks.

```
scale=10
loops=10
function runQuery (){
   loop=1
   lower=1
   upper=scale
   while [ $loop -le $loops ]; do
      echo "Loop -> $loop between $lower and $upper" 
      mysql -NB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "$query" 
      let loop=$loop+1
      let lower=lower+scale
      let upper=upper+scale
   done
}

query='delete from x where id between $lower and $upper'
runQuery
```

In the example above the variables are set to an empty string when the query is passed in rather than `$lower` and `$upper` being used within the function. I am guessing what I need to do is pass in a placeholder for the variable which will be defined within the function... The variables are being correctly substituted in in the echo statement but are not in the `query`. I could easily just put the query in the function, but I want to be able run this on multiple tables and send in different queries without having to duplicate all the looping variable set up throughout the script.

I have done quite a bit of searching for this but not sure I am searching for the right things...

BASH VERSION 3.2

Comment: That was a just a typo while removing part of the echo statement from the actual code. I fixed it above and still have the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you pass the query as a parameter?

Comment: I just tried that by calling:
replacing
```runQuery```
with 
```runQuery "$query"``` 

and it's still not using the values for $upper and $lower in the actual query...

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansion is performed on a string just once, i.e. `"$query"` expands to `delete from x where id between $lower and $upper` and that's all, bash doesn't expand `$lower` and `$upper`.

Anyway, this is not a good idea at all, any possible workaround will make your script open to code injection.

So, if your `printf` support `-v` option, create a query template like this:

```
query_templ='delete from x where id between %d and %d'
```

and use it to generate queries:

```
printf -v 'query' "$query_templ" "$lower" "$upper"
mysql -NB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "$query"
```

Comment: I added that and got this error: 
```${query@P}: bad substitution``` I looked up this error and found a couple of articles related and tried some of the other @ options and they all failed as well...

Comment: My prompt is actually not a $, that's part of the error... @Roadowl

Answer (score 0):

```
function runQuery (){
   loop=1
   lower=1
   upper=$scale
   while [ $loop -le $loops ]; do
      echo "Loop -> $loop between $lower and $upper" 
      mysql -NB -h 127.0.0.1 -e `eval echo "$query"`
      let loop=$loop+1
      let lower=lower+scale
      let upper=upper+scale
   done
}

scale=10; loops=10
query='delete from x where id between $lower and $upper'
runQuery "$query"
```